# Evaluation maps over polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

just looking for feedback and/or hints about this proof I've been working on. No answers please, but I'd like to know if I'm on the right track here.

So I'm given a field $F$, and a non-zero $n \times n$ matrix $M$ with entries in $F$, and that $ev_M:F[x] \rightarrow M_{n\times n}(F)$ is a ring homomorphism where $ev_M(f(x)) = f(M) = ev_M(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n)$ is defined to be $a_0+a_1M+a_2M^2+...a_nM^n$, and I am asked to show that there is a unique polynomial $h(x) \in F[x]$ such that $h(M) = 0_M$ and $deg$ $h(x) \leq deg$ $f(x)$ whenever $f(M) = 0_M$.

Edited solution: 
Note that the kernel of $ev_M$ is non-trivial, because $ev_M$ is not injective. Since the kernel is a subset of $F[x]$, and every ideal of $F[x]$ is principal, $ker$ $ev_M =$ $<h(x)>$, for some unique irreducible polynomial of lowest degree.

If there is a polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$ such that $f(M)=0$, then $f(x)\in ker$ $ev_M$. Since $h(x)$ generates the kernel, either $f(x) = h(x)$ or $f(x) = h(x)g(x)$, for some $g(x)\in ker$ $ev_M$.

Finally, we conclude by noting that $h(M)=0$, and $deg$ $h(x)$ is always less than or equal to $deg$ $f(x)$.

Comment: You seem to essentially have it, but there is one confusion: you're neither given $f$ nor looking for it, so there are no cases to go through on $f$. The zero polynomial has undefined degree, so while $0(M)=0$ will always hold, it has nothing to do with the argument. Ah-perhaps you just wanted to write $h$ for $f$ in the first sentence of each paragraph of your solution. You should mention why you know the kernel of $ev$ has a single generator, and consider whether it's in fact possible that $h=0$.

Comment: I was using $f$ to show that whenever $f(M)=0$, we have this unique polynomial $h$. I am a little confused by how I need them to relate, do you have any further insight? I know the kernel of $ev$ is an ideal, so it is generated by some irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ with non-zero degree. $h$ couldn't be the zero polynomial, because then we would have a trivial kernel, right?

Comment: The logic's backward there-we have this unique polynomial $h$, such that whenever $f(M)=0$ the degree of $h$ is no more than that of $f$. The order matters-you can't choose a new $h$ for every $f$! So start with looking at the ideal and picking $h$, and then observe that it has the minimal possible degree. The last sentence of your comment is true, but why can't we have a trivial kernel?

Comment: Ok, that makes much more sense. The wording of the problem as it was given to me was confusing me, I was reading it as if $f(M)=0$, then there exists an $h$, but I think you're saying that if there exists an $h$, then $f(M) = 0$? As for why the kernel cannot be trivial, I think it's because the kernel being trivial implies that $ev_M$ is injective, which it obviously is not. For some nilpotent matrix $M$ of degree 2, both the zero polynomial and all polynomials of the form $0+0x^1+a_2x^2$ get sent to $0_M$.

Comment: Not to be picky, but saying something is obvious still isn't a justification. Not all matrices are nilpotent. Your second sentence still isn't the right wording: there *does* exist an h such that for all f...

Comment: Well, I was more trying to show an example of how the map is not one-to-one, so that I could be justified in saying that the kernel is non-trivial. What would be a better way of saying that?

Comment: What is the dimension of the vector space of all $n×n$ matrices? How many of the matrix powers of $M$ can be linearly independent?